# Can a man address a woman with sama 様【さま】?

Tags: usage, honorifics, suffixes

I've seen Japanese women address their husbands with the -sama suffix.  Would it be appropriate for a man do the same in some cases? In which context can this be used?

Comment: "I've seen Japanese women address their husbands with the -sama suffix" I'm curious, where? I can't deny it happens, but it strikes me as quite unusual. -san is very common, though.

Comment: I would have said the most common way I have wives address their husbands is the word あなた, however it would seem like a rare occurrence to use ~様 with someone you knew well unless it was a joke.

Comment: @dainichi Movie called "Rurouni Kenshin". One girl in this movie constantly called her beloved man -sama.

Comment: I see. Just be aware that a lot of historical fiction contains, if not decidedly historically wrong, then heavily stylized language.

Comment: @dainichi Got it. Thank you, I'll be aware.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

～様 is an honorific and can be easily thought of as a more respectful version of ～さん. It is gender neutral, so it can be used by both men and women when addressing either gender.

It is often used when addressing someone of a higher social position, or someone for whom you have high regards. On a day-to-day basis, it's commonly used to address customers.